Remove feature from kernel matrix
I am pretty new to machine learning so please bear with me :)
I am trying to do a binary classification task using an SVM with precomuted kernel (in python using sklearn).
I created my train kernel but I have included a feature that I wasn't meant to and that isn't present in the test data. I don't have a very thorough understanding of what exactly the kernel is apart from the "distances" between data points but is it possible to remove this feature from the train kernel without having to generate a new one?
I hope this makes sense and again bear with me as I am very new to this.
